# Is there the exact same frequency-multiple between any-2 successive keys in any keyboard-instrument?

Tags: scales, frequency

The pattern of key arrangement in harmonium/keyboard/piano is like this:

[image: key pattern], where I can see 2-types of condition between 2 successive keys.

**1: black to white (or white to black) (say their freq. (Hz) is X-times different)**

**2: white to white (say their frequency is y-times different)**

(3: There is no 2 black side by side)

Now **is *x* = *y*** ? i.e the **frequency**-**multiplier** between **any-2 successive keys** are same?

I can't conclude this by judging it through ear; because just like each ***x*** sounds the same to each ***y***;  from this pattern, if I play **only the white-keys**; still I sense there difference as the same (i. e ***m*=*n***); and if I play **only the black-keys**, I sense (hear) their difference as same, too (i.e. ***u*=*v***).

(what a bizarre illusion!!! hats of to who designed the scale)

Now any 1 of them is correct. which one?

*P.S. As well I'm not a musical person and never learnt music. so please elaborate/hyperlink about terminologies.*

Comment: Isn't this where 12edo (12et) comes in? But not the same *frequency difference* but *ratio*. Frequency difference just can't work.

Comment: Could you help what to search about  that 'ratio'?

Comment: @Tim please feel free to edit my question to make it more useful.

Comment: @Tim thanks you've understood correctly what I was trying to tell. Should I replace all the "frequency difference" with "frequency multiple"?

Comment: That would be more in line with what you're trying to establish.

Comment: I've improved the question. Still any cause for downvote? I'm not seeking any upvote, I'm just asking for the cause behind this downvote.

Comment: The downvotes are likely coming from the fact that you'd invented an idea and then asked about that idea, rather than asking directly about the underlying relationship between notes.  It is also quite hard to follow since your graphic and wording seems to be related to the physical distance between keys on the keyboard -- which is both varied and meaningless from a theoretical standpoint -- instead of with regard to actual notes.

Comment: There is also zero innate different between white notes and black notes; it's purely to aid playing, which is why other instruments played differently do not have such an obvious distinction between adjacent semitones.  There are even keyboards where every key is physically identical.  TL;DR: Make fewer assumptions, and start your questions from a more basic level while you learn!

Comment: As for the ratio of 2: A note and its octave differ by a factor of two.  In your diagram, the white key furthest to the left has a frequency that is 1/2 of the white key 3rd from the right, etc.

Comment: @MatthewRead please feel free to edit the question to make it useful; I had no intention to make any new theory... I've just asked my query, and maybe what I'm thinking as an illusion for me, is merely a poor-observation. However I've got my answer and ticked it. If declaring it as a community wiki is helpful, I could do that.

Comment: U and v cannot be the same frequency distance apart, as u is a minor third whilst v is a major second. The idea is that any interval that is the same as another will have the same relative pitch differential ( if I've phrased it correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In almost all cases the tuning standard for modern keyboards is [12-tone equal temeperament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal_temperament).  This has the feature that the frequency **ratio** between two successive (chromatic) notes is `2^(1/12)` approximately 1.05946309435. Our ears, to a good approximation, hear pitch as the logarithm of the frequency, so each black-to-white (or white-to-black, or between two adjacent white keys w/o a black between them) seems like the same step size.

Due to the characteristics of their strings, in practice the tuning of pianos does not [exactly conform to 12-TET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_acoustics#The_Railsback_curve), in order that the pianos actually sound good.

Most synthesized sounds more accurately conform to the standard.

Comment: Whilst this answer relates well to modern 12edo tuned instruments, it's actually not a complete answer. More to come, I expect. Even pianos are not tuned to agree with this!

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to consider about pianos is that most of the notes have multiple strings. I believe each string is also tuned slightly differently to make the notes fit better in relation to different key signatures.

Comment: Check your information source. I think eac of the 2 or 3 strings on a particular note need to be the same pitch, otherwise there will be some beating occurring, which is not necessarily a good sound for a piano note.